# Div toggle disappear after button search click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to do a simple thing with jQuery.

There's a button called `showDiv` to show or hide a search div and it's working perfectly.

But inside the div, I have text and a button to search, after I've shown the div, assuming someone has typed some text in `TextBox1` to search for.

However, if I type in `TextBox1` and click `searchButton`, the div goes into the hide position.

I think this is because of the page reloading, but I don't know how I fix it.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=showDiv.ClientID%>').click(function (evt) {
            $("#<%=myDiv.ClientID%>").slideToggle("slow");
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>


<asp:Button ID="showDiv" runat="server" Text="Show/Hide Div" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="display:none">
    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Serach Button" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this within a form element?

Comment: Well yes, it's because of the page reload. Since you submitted your form it reloaded and you have `style="display:none"` at your div so the default when it loads is it's not displayed

Comment: @Matt Fletcher no it's a content page, child of master

Comment: @crimson589 yeah, but I search for a solution to keep Div open until user click to Button to close it

Answer (score 0):

### Updated:

**Note:** Button `searchButton` must not have a click method

```
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Serach Button" />
```

---

Add a temp button and make it hide by setting style to display:none :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInvisible" runat="server" style="display: none" 
    OnClick="btnInvisible_Click" />
```

And in jQuery:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=searchButtin.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
            $('#<%=btnInvisible.ClientID%>').click();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Click method in server-side:

```
protected void btnInvisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //... code for searching...
}
```

Comment: Div toggle not working after I Click in 'showDiv' Button

Comment: try removing this: `$("#<%=myDiv.ClientID%>").slideToggle("slow");`

Comment: one more removing first line not second `document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';` and see ?

Comment: toggle now working, But still when i search for any thing, typing in textbox then the Div hiding ! this is my original question

Comment: thank U for your efforts, but still if I typing any think inside textbox and click in 'searchButton' .. The Div hiding

Comment: unfortunately, still Div hiding after I Click searchButton

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use asp control must be manage the postback and toggle method in server side

add on click method to showDiv button and write this code

```
<asp:Button ID="showDiv" runat="server" CssClass="showDiv" Text="Show/Hide Div" OnClick="showDiv_Click"/>
```

and server side code is

```
protected void showDiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (myDiv.Style["Display"] == "none")
        {
            myDiv.Style["Display"] = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            myDiv.Style["Display"] = "none";
        }
    }
```

and for the page load method in server side code must be

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack){
         myDiv.Style["Display"] = "none";
        }

    }
```

if you must use thr jquery method it's better use the html button and manage it'display from jquery

and another approach is in the Search button click method write this code

```
<asp:Button ID="searchButton"  runat="server" Text="Serach Button" OnClick="searchButton_Click" />

protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            myDiv.Style["Display"] = "block";

    }
```

and set display property in the page load method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack){
         myDiv.Style["Display"] = "none";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank U, this is not my issue, I want use javascript not c# code behind

Comment: do you use asp button Forced or you can use html button؟